# Add UISearchBar to UITableView programmatically not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

**Background:** I have a `UIViewController` that, when loads, has a `UITableView` generated programmatically that gets its data from an `SQLite3` database.  This works fine.

**Problem:** I need to add a `UISearchBar` (and associated logic) but when I try, the UISearcBar is not rendered.

**Code so far:**

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "sqlite3.h"
#import "Exhibitor.h"
@interface ExhibitorViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate>
{
    sqlite3 *congressDB;
    NSMutableArray *searchData;
    UISearchBar *searchBar;
    UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

-(NSString *) filePath;
-(void)openDB;

@end
```

.m file where the UISearchBar is added:

```
-(void)loadTableView
{
    CGRect usableSpace = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    CGFloat usableWidth = usableSpace.size.width;
    CGFloat usableHeight = usableSpace.size.height;

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    [tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,usableWidth, usableHeight)];
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    tableView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar; // I think this should have loaded the searchBar but doesn't

    // [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:searchBar]; // Have also tried this
    // [self.tableView.tableHeaderView addSubview:searchBar];  // And this
    NSLog(@"searchBar = %@", searchBar);  // This shows the searchBar is an object with values
    NSLog(@"HeaderView = %@", self.tableView.tableHeaderView);  // This shows the tableHeaderView as null ?? 

}
```

What am I doing wrong?  What do I need to do to add a `UISearchBar` programmatically to a `UITableView` within a `UIVewController`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use a `UITableViewController` instead...

**.h**

```
@interface ExhibitorViewController : UITableViewController <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate> {
    sqlite3 *congressDB;
    NSMutableArray *searchData;
    UISearchBar *searchBar;
    UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;
}

-(NSString *) filePath;
-(void)openDB;

@end
```

**.m**

```
-(void)loadTableView {

    searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 64)];
    searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
    searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar; 

}
```

The problem is you were creating a table view but not assigning it to the property, and using `UITableViewController` makes things much simpler anyway...

If you want to keep it the way it is now, then you could just put `self.tableView = tableVew;` after `[self.view addSubview:tableView];`...

Comment: Is there a way of implementing this with a UITableView within a UIVewController rather than a UITableViewController?  I have graphical styling (drop shadows etc) on the UIVeiwController that don't appear to be possible on a UITableViewController.

Comment: That's fixed it, many thanks.  This has also helped me spot a few more things to clean up in my code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that

```
self.tableView
```

in loadTableView is nil or it is not that table that you have created programmatically.

Add

```
self.tableView = tableView;
```

after

```
[self.view addSubview:tableView];
```

Without this your searchBar is added to invalid tableView.

should

Comment: This answer is also right but I marked @jjv360 as the correct answer as he illustrated where I went wrong quite well. Thanks for your time though.

Comment: You can add +1 for my answer if you like it.